# Juniper SSG 550 - interfaces on the ha zone not set

Tags: juniper

I am trying to set up HA on a pair of Juniper SSG550s with ScreenOS 6.1.0r2.0

The machines have multiple interfaces, configured as redundant pairs:

red1 -> eth0/0 and eth0/1
red2 -> eth0/1 and eth0/2

If I try to set up the vlan to the HA zone, I get an error and HA is not one of the available zones.

```
dbcluster:SSG520(M)-> set int red1.102 tag 102 zone ha
                                               ^----unknown keyword ha
dbcluster:SSG520(M)-> set int red1.102 tag 102 zone trust
```

So I then try to set the red1 interface:

```
dbcluster:SSG520(M)-> get int
..
eth0/0         0.0.0.0/0                         Trust       0010.dbff.4000    -   D   0  
eth0/1         0.0.0.0/0                         Trust       0010.dbff.4050    -   U   0  
..
red1           0.0.0.0/0                         Trust       0010.dbff.4600    -   U   0  
vlan1          0.0.0.0/0                         VLAN        0010.dbff.40f0    1   D   0  
null           0.0.0.0/0                         Null        N/A               -   U   0  
SSG520(M)-> set int red1 ha   
SSG520(M)-> get int

..
eth0/0         0.0.0.0/0                         Trust       0010.dbff.4000    -   D   0  
eth0/1         0.0.0.0/0                         Trust       0010.dbff.4050    -   U   0  
red1           0.0.0.0/0                         Trust       0010.dbff.4600    -   U   0  
vlan1          0.0.0.0/0                         VLAN        0010.dbff.40f0    1   D   0  
null           0.0.0.0/0                         Null        N/A               -   U   0  
..
```

As you can see, the HA part gets completely ignored.

Is it possible to use redundant interfaces for HA at all? It already looks like it's impossible to use VLANs for this but, do you actually need dedicated interfaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you need dedicated interfaces as far as I know.

Every pair I've setup has used a direct crossover cable for the HA interface.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid doing so as the device only has 6 interfaces and the lead time to get pims is in the two month range.